# Populate navigation properties automatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've this -simplified- model class:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual UserResource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

And an Mvc Web Api Controller:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Transaction transaction)
{
}
```

And my request body is like this:

```
{"Id":"5520AEB9-DAD8-4C85-80A7-3257931B9790","ResourceId":"118547FC-0B3A-4816-820C-93BF2BA1BF14"}
```

In the post method, transaction.Resource is null. And I don't know how to get it to be populated using the Resource Id I passed...

What I tried so far:

1. Add `public string ResourceId {get; set;}` and mark it as a ForeignKey in Transaction... -> no change
2. In the request change ResourceId param to "Resource":{Id:".."} -> transaction.Resource is not null any more but it hasn't queried Resource table to fill in anything...
3. Mark Resource as virtual or not (Lazy loading or Eager) -> No change

Ideas?

Comment: Your json does not have a `Resource` property. For your attemp #2, are  you expecting the framework to fetch from your database a `Resource` object by the `ResourceId`?

Comment: i don't know about EF7 , but what i know you should have a DBContext object then attache your model to it to get model populated from database

Comment: @FrankFajardo, True.

Comment: @mfarouk, the db context is aware of all of these models already. I can query for them... etc. it's just not populating those -navigation- properties when passed ids in a request...

Comment: @HaythamAbuelFutuh i don't think Web API controller will create the DBContext for you, you should create it, then attach your entity object to it to be aware about the it
follow this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx
section "Attaching an existing entity to the context"

Comment: @HaythamAbuelFutuh, if you are expecting the framework OOB to *parameter bind* a full `Resource` object from your database, to your WebAPI method parameter, and you simply give it a `ResourceId`, you are asking for magic.Also, normally, you would have a `ResourceId` property on your `Transaction` model, so `Resource` is only a navigation property, as opposed to being mapped to database column. In that case, you simply supply a `ResourceId` property with the `Transaction` object you pass to your method, *provided that is actually the intention of your POST action*.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `Resource` object to your API, you must either pass it in or have the API figure out what it is, I don't suggest the latter.

So as it's Entity Framework 7, you can't use lazy loading at this point in time as it's not (yet) in the framework.

The current [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap) lists it as a high priority and they state:

> These features are high priority but we think EF7 would be a compelling release for the vast majority of applications without them.

So instead, in your query you need to manually include all of your navigation properties, for example:

```
var data = context.Transactions
    .Include(t => t.Resource)
    .Where(t => t.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm interested in what should I do in my Post method?

Comment: Nothing different if the app that posts the data is posting it all correctly.